# Content Script doesn't run when I set a "default_popup" in an extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

My content script and background script run perfectly when I don't set a default popup. When I do the latter somehow both the background and the content script don't give any output in the console.

1.manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "KS Scrapper",
    "description":"Simple Scrapper",
    "version" : "1.0.0",
    "icons":{"128":"images/ks_logo_128.png"},
    "browser_action" : {
        "default_icon" : "images/ks_logo_19.png",
        "default_popup" : "popup.html"
    },
    "content_scripts" : [
            {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js" : ["jquery-2.1.4.min.js", "popup.js"],
            "css" : ["c.css"]
        }
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "css/style.css"
    ],
    "permissions": ["tabs"],
    "background":{
        "scripts":["background.js"]
    }
}
```

2.popup.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(gotMessage);

function gotMessage(message, sender, sendResponse){
    console.log(message);
    if(message!=null){
        var b = document.getElementById("get_url");
        document.getElementById("url").value = message;
    } }
```

3.background.js

```
console.log("background running")

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(buttonClicked)

function buttonClicked(tab){
    function getLink() {
        chrome.tabs.query({
            active: true,
            currentWindow: true
        }, function (tabs) {
            var tabURL = tabs[0].url;
            console.log(tabURL);
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, tabURL)
            console.log("message sent");
        });
    }
    getLink();

}
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could share a solution or guide me on anything in particular that I have to redo or research on. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `default_popup` and `browserAction.onClicked` are mutually exclusive. [`browserAction.onClicked`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#event-onClicked) doesn't fire if `default_popup` is present.

Comment: Also, the name `popup.js` implies you're incorrectly loading it both as a content script and as an extension script inside popup.html. Note that the popup is a separate page with its own DOM, document, window, URL.